# Column Validation not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-validation

I'm trying to put the following formula into column validation:  [Title]="Job Request"
When I save it, it gets replaced with:  =Title="Job Request" and does not work properly.
It seemed to hold the formula as I entered it yesterday and validated perfectly but not today.

Comment: The change in how the formula looks is expected and shouldn't be a problem. What do you mean by not working properly? When you go to save the list item if anything but `Job Request` is in the title field, you should get an error.

Comment: Did you apply this column validation on "Title" column under column settings? This formula will save the list item only when Title column is equal to "Job Request". Is this the expected behavior? If No, let us know how you want it to behave & we will be able to help you with correct formula.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance change of the validation formula in this column is correct and will not affect normal work.

[image]

If you apply this Column Validation on the "Title" column in the list, it means that the list item will only be saved if the "Title" column is equal to "Job Request".

[image]

Column Verification does not work. Does it mean that the item can be saved even if the "Title" column value is not "Job Request" ? Or "Title" column value is equal to "Job Request", the page also displays Error: Column Validation Failed?

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

1.Clear browser cache

2.Use other browsers for testing

3.Check if set **Validation settings** for the list

[image]

[image]